# I am new to programming and need to store the below input in one array. Any suggestions?

Tags: java

Below is the code I am working with. I just need to store the input in an array and Im pretty lost!

```
package Code.simpleInput;
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LEDSetter
    {
    private static Scanner sc;

public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
    // Instantiating the Finch object
    Finch myFinch = new Finch();
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Providing instructions to the user

    System.out.println("Enter the red, green, and blue intensity for the LED (values from 0 to 255)");

    // Reading in the three integers
    System.out.print("Red: <=200 ");
    int red = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Green: <=250 ");
    int green = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Blue: <=250 ");
    int blue = sc.nextInt();

    /* Potential improvement here - check the user input to make sure that it is in range (0-255) */

    // Setting the LED

    System.out.println("Thanks, the beak will now glow for 8 seconds according to your specifications");

    myFinch.setLED(red,green,blue);
    myFinch.sleep(8000);

    // Always end your program with finch.quit()

    myFinch.quit();
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have three int values in an array, then

```
int[] inputs = new int[3];
...
...   
sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
// Providing instructions to the user    
System.out.println("Enter the red, green, and blue intensity for the LED (values from 0 to 255)");    
// Reading in the three integers    
System.out.print("Red: <=200 ");    
int red = sc.nextInt();    
inputs[0] = red;
System.out.print("Green: <=250 ");    
int green = sc.nextInt();    
inputs[1] = green;    
System.out.print("Blue: <=250 ");    
int blue = sc.nextInt();      
inputs[2] = blue;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Create an array
int[] arr = new int[3];

//store the values using the index
arr[0] = red;
arr[1] = green;
arr[2] = blue;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This definitely helped me set up my array. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
System.out.print("Red: <=200 ");
int red = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Green: <=250 ");
int green = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Blue: <=250 ");
int blue = sc.nextInt();

int colors[] ={red,green,blue};
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! This was a very effective way for me to fit this array in. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> inputs=new ArrayList<Integer>();
inputs.add(sc.nextInt());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have not yet used an ArrayList so this was interesting to see. Thanks again!

Comment: you should accept the answer which solved ur question :)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare an int array like below if you know the number of input elements.

```
      int[] inputArray = new int[size]; 
      int[0] = sc.nextInt();
      int[1] = sc.nextInt(); 
      int[2] = sc.nextInt();
```

and now you can use your array. But if you are not sure of number of elements then go with ArrayList. Here type should be a object and not a primitive.

```
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Interger>();  
      list.add(sc.nextInt());
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and store them using an index using:

```
//Create the array

int[] arr = new int[3];

//Store the values using the index

arr[0] = sc.nextInt();

arr[1] = sc.nextInt();

arr[2] = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public enum ColorEnum 
    {
      Red(getValue("Red","200")),
      Green(getValue("Green","250")),
      Blue(getValue("Blue","250"));

      final int value;
    private static int getValue(String Color,String Range)
    {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(Color+" : <="+Range);
      return sc.nextInt();
    }


       ColorEnum(int value) {
          this.value = value;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just needed to see the set up so this was very useful, thanks again!